# Is it good for the SharePoint developer to learn React.js and Typescript?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am currently working as sharepoint developer in a product based company.We are moving ahead and enhancing our products to work with react.js and typescripts and other technologies. but a major thing to notice is that we are not dependent on SharePoint anymore. i.e. our new product will work indepent from sharepoint.

So my question is, as i have a profile of sharepoint developer is it beneficial to work in that product and learn and understand React.js and Typescript ? Will it be beneficial in the future for me for the Profile of SharePoint developer?

Please reply as I am confused with this..

**EDIT :**
Also, Is it good to be a sharepoint developer or a .net developer with intermediate knowledge on both technologies?

Thanks

Comment: *SharePoint*'s UI is heavily based on Javascript nowadays, so definitely yes. *Especially* for Typescript

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be help full for you to develop on SharePoint online and 2016, because microsoft is introduced new platform for SharePoint SPfx. It is completely with Typescript and the React.js is recommended for this. All the best.